# Ionic - $state.go works on livereload but not on device

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, state

I am experiencing a weird issue with the following. On livereload or on browser, state.go function works properly as expected. However when I run the app on device (without livereload), the app do not apply the transition to the new state.

This is how I call the function:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right"><a class="button button-clear navButtons" ng-click="setSelectedForEdit(selectedChannel)">DÜZENLE</a></ion-nav-buttons>
```

And this is the controller:

```
.controller('ChannelCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state, firebaseDataService) {

  $scope.setSelectedForEdit = function(channelUniqueID) {     
    $state.go('app.channel-edit', {'channelId':channelUniqueID});  
  };       
})
```

And my route the following:

```
.state('app.channel-edit', {
        url: '/channels/:channelId/edit',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/ChannelEdit.html',
                controller: 'ChannelEditCtrl'
            }
        },
        cache: false
    })
```

Anybody have experienced the same before?

Comment: Is the channelUniqueID populated in the state.go method in your mobile view ?

Comment: What error does it throw on your mobile? You can check with Google Chrome your connected devices

Comment: @Srijith I am not sure what you meant exactly but it is a rootscope variable.

Comment: @Greg Lol I did not know that I could check with chrome if I run without livereload. :) It was giving a GET file:///android_asset/www/templates/ChannelEdit.html not found error. Thanks for tip. For anybody else experiencing the same; I renamed my template from ChannelEdit.html to channeledit.html, and changing this line: templateUrl: 'templates/ChannelEdit.html' to templateUrl: 'templates/channeledit.html' solved my issue. Weird that it was running proper with livereload though.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The file of one of my controllers started with uppercase, I changed it to lowercase and this solved my issue.